# Excel Offset function understanding

Tags: excel-formula

Thanks for reading my question

```
=OFFSET(E5,45,CL5+2)
```

This function is in cell E5 so from E5 I should be able to simply count down 45 rows and then go to CL5+1 which I think should be CM50. The problem is the value in CM50 is 109 which should the value that shows up in E5 if I understand what offset is doing but what I actually get in E5 is a value of 102.

Also the value in CL5 is 179 and CL50 value is 15

So clearly I'm not understanding what I've read about what Offset is doing, I read some examples here on stack overflow and MSoffice but I'm still not quite sure what it's doing?

Thanks any help would be great

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
=OFFSET(E5,45,column(CL5)-column(E5)+1)
```

The issue is it is looking at the value of CL5 and using that value as the offset, when what appears is wanted is the column.

For a non volatile function you can use INDEX():

```
=INDEX(E:CM,ROW(E5)+45,COLUMN(CL5)-COLUMN(E5)+2)
```

But in this specific instance, which I assume you have greatly simplified, you could simply put:

```
=CM50
```

Comment: Yes I'm greatly simplifying the formula  which actually uses offset twice with a BitAND function. I seem to do the math for the BitAnd correctly but I'm totally missing what is going on with the offset, it seems non of the numbers I see it creating like in this case why in E5 do I see 102 when CL5 has 179, CL50 has 15 and CM50 has 109

Comment: @RickFlyFish Like I said in my answer, It is looking at the value in CL5 and using that value as the horizontal offset. so it is returning the value from 45 rows down and 180 columns to the right which is GC50 not CM50. If you want the column 1 to the right of CL then you need to use what I put in my answer.

Comment: Oh, I think I see so if CL5 is 179 + 2 rather than the +1 I mistakenly had in my question then it will be looking at GD which is 102....

Comment: Thanks very much I get what's going on now! thank you